# Autolayout is not working with NSSplitView and NSPageController with Storyboard. Is this Apple Bug?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I just created a empty project on github --> [here](https://github.com/patchthecode/PageControllerError/archive/master.zip) <-- to demonstrate the problem (Done in objective-c)

The project is a simple storyboard project. An NSWindowController loads an NSPageController which loads a NSSplitView containing 3 panes. There is no code in the sample project, except the code to load the screens. When the project runs, it looks like this [image].

How do I get the constraints to make the splitView stretch all the way to the ends when the window is resized? The weird thing is, if you Switch the NSWindowController's contentController from the NSPageController to the NSSplitViewController, then every thing works as expected. Is this Apple Bug? I would appreciate any answer swift/objectivec please. I've tried but nothing works.

**[EDIT]** - Based on the answer below and further researching (contacted Apple), it appears that NSPageViewController does not use autolayout constraints but relies on autoresizing mask and frame setting on its children views.

So when the page controller creates its view controllers, we should set this:

```
-(NSViewController *)pageController:(NSPageController *)pageController viewControllerForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    [viewController.view setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable)];
    return viewController;
}
```

With this, the problem is fixed. I wish as an update in future, this control works with Autolayout constraints as it seems more natural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had many problems with `NSPageController`. I found that the solution is to not use auto layout with it.

Try to use the `NSAutoresizingMaskOptions` on your `NSSplitView`. 
First, remove all constraints inside the `NSPageController`.

Then:

```
splitView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
splitView.frame = pageController.view.bounds;
```

*or*

```
splitView.autoresizingMask = [.ViewWidthSizable, .ViewHeightSizable]
splitView.frame = pageController.view.bounds
```

**EDIT**

Made a project based on yours [here](https://github.com/mangerlahn/SplitViewPageControllerLayoutTest)

Comment: Hi, ok where in my code do i put this? I've tried putting this into my code but it doesnt work. I have the same code above, would you mind telling me which part to put it?

Comment: I used it in the viewDidLoad of the main view controller that holds the NSPageController.

Comment: Ok. one question, did you mean you used it in your code this way? or did you mean you used it in the code i provided above? Because in the code i provided above, the viewDidLoad doesnt have a reference to the splitView.. The reference code above also uses a storyboard

Comment: Sorry, I missed your code. I looked into it and was not able to fix it. The view would size properly, but when having multiple controllers, the bug still occurs - I will take a look into it tomorrow

Comment: Your answer is correct. If you dont update your posted answer to reflect what you did in your code, then i'll do it later. Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0):

I also got same issue in Pagecontroller:

And solved it by using the given code:

```
 func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, viewControllerForIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSViewController {
    switch identifier {
    case "formController":
        let controller = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "formController") as! FormController
        controller.view.autoresizingMask = [.height , .width]
        return controller
    default:
        return self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! NSViewController
    }
}

func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, identifierFor object: Any) -> String {

    return String(describing: object)

}

func pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition(_ pageController: NSPageController) {
    print(pageController.selectedIndex)

    pageController.completeTransition()
     pageController.selectedViewController!.view.autoresizingMask = [.height , .width]

}
```